# Embeding VBA into sheet to show/Hide Form control based on value of a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have used a combo box form control and have inputs 1, 2, and 3 linked to it. I have used cell link C2 for my output. I am trying to add VBA code to a sheet to recognize that if a value in cell "C2" is a number 1 to display form control button3. If it is any other value to not display 'Button3' and the form control will be hidden.

I have come up with this:

```
Sub Display_KPI_FORMS()

If Range("C2").Value = 1 Then

        Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Button3").Visible = msoFalse
        Else
        Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Button3").Visible = msoTrue
    End If

End Sub
```

It gives an error saying the item with specified name not found.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default name for form buttons includes a space.  The logic in your `If Then Else` block contradicts your statement.  You can remove the `If` statement and just use the code below.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Button 3").Visible = Range("C2").Value = 1
```

---

```
Sub Display_Forms()

    With Sheets("KPI Summary")
        .Shapes("T1M").Visible = Range("R2").Value = 1
        .Shapes("T1Q").Visible = Range("R2").Value = 3
        .Shapes("T1Y").Visible = Range("R2").Value = 12
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, Thanks for your comment. It works a treat.

Comment: Hi Thomas, you are welcome. I'm glad I was able to help.

Comment: Hey Thomas, I wanted to add other values then will it have to be modified into an if statement?                                                                                                              Sub Display_Forms()
Sheets("KPI Summary").Shapes("T1M").Visible = Range("R2").Value = 1
Sheets("KPI Summary").Shapes("T1Q").Visible = Range("R2").Value = 3
Sheets("KPI Summary").Shapes("T1Y").Visible = Range("R2").Value = 12
End Sub

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using the `If` statement.  I prefer the shorthand method because it has the same effect and doesn't clog up the screen.  I want to be able to read the whole procedure without have to scroll up and down.

Comment: Also notice how I use the `With` statement to make the code more condensed and easier to read.

Comment: I recommend watching the Wise Owl Tutorials on Youtube: [Introduction to VBA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHO5NIcZAc4&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).

Comment: Nice Thanks for that Thomas. I have added it to my watch list. Cheers